# citrix keeps breaking after every OS update

Tags: windows-10, citrix-receiver

anybody understands why is my Citrix client always broken after seemingly every Windows update I install?

[image]

I tried downloading citrix client from www.citrix.com but when I tried to install it failed with error, that this is not the latest version. But I just downloaded it! Next time I tried to get this ICAWebWrapper.msi and store it to use it next time this happens, but it does not take it and says it's not valid installation file.
Seems like the only solution to this is to completely uninstall citrix client, download and install again! Jeez...
I have currently Citrix Workspace 1810 (18.10.0.20023). I need some solution so this stops happening. Any ideas?

Comment: just glancing online, this is a very generic error and has been around for a long time.  Unfortunately, it applies to a lot of different problems.  Have you spoken to whoever is in charge of your Citrix related applications?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by being "in charge" of citrix apps? Do you mean those who maintain the portal and published apps? It don't think they have anything to do with my laptop and software on it... the problem is not server side.

Comment: Do you make a habit of clearing out your temporary files?

Comment: I guess I used disk cleanup wizard recently before this happened. But it seems pretty silly to me if Citrix relies on the install files to remain in some temp folders... Windows 10 does cleanup of those folders by itself too and user can schedule this.